# How to pass data to viewController without creating its object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a iOS static library in which user will pass the name of the `Viewontroller` and some `parameters` inside the push and I am getting these details in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and from here I got a string suppose `NSString *vcName = @"ViewController2"` and parameter suppose `NSString *param1= @"UserName"` `NSString *param2= @"email"` now I want to pass these parameters to the viewController Which name's string is received from push. But I don't want to write `#import ViewController2`.

I am able to redirect to `ViewController2` without importing it but don't know how to pass these parameters to `ViewController2`

I can redirect to the viewController from the following code.

```
NSString *vcName = @"ViewController2";
NSString *param1= @"UserName";
NSString *param2= @"user_email";
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController].storyboard;
UIViewController *vcToOpen = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:vcName]];

vcToOpen.modalPresentationStyle =UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:vcToOpen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now I want to get these two parameter's value in `ViewController2`. Can anybody help me how to do it. without writing `#import ViewController2` because app can has many `ViewControllers` and `vcName` can be any of them.

Comment: you can use global string or define in appdelegate method

Comment: I think not't possible or if you want to do it forcefully then you have to do it using inefficient way like store parameter value in NSUserDefault or some where else and get back that from NSUserDefault or else where on ViewDidLoad and assign that value to particular variable of viewcontroller.

Comment: you can use shared class for this

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate.h

```
-(NSString *)getEmail;
-(NSString *)getName;
-(void)setEmail:(NSString *)email Name:(NSString *)name;
+(AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    NSString *strEmail, *strName;
}

-(NSString *)getEmail
{
    return strEmail;
}

-(NSString *)getName
{
    return strName;
}

-(void)setEmail:(NSString *)email Name:(NSString *)name
{
    strEmail = email;
    strName = name;
}

+(AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

ViewController1.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void)gotoViewController2
{
    [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] setEmail:@"email@gmail.com" Name:@"name1234"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToViewController2" sender:nil];
}
```

ViewController2.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *name = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]getName];
    NSString *email = [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]getEmail];
    NSLog(@"name = %@ and email = %@",name, email); //name = name1234 and email = email@gmail.com
}
```

Comment: another options is take global constant and NSUserDefault (Preference)

Answer (score 0):

Storing values in your app delegate is just messy.

Each one of your UIViewControllers that could be launched from a push notification could conform to a custom 'launch' protocol.

Each UIViewController e.g. 'UIViewController2' would conform to this protocol.

You could write the protocol like this:

```
@protocol LaunchProtocol <NSObject>
- (void) launchParams:(NSDictionary *)params;
@end
```

Each UIViewController could conform to this protocol, like so:

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController <LaunchProtocol>
@end

@implementation ViewController2
- (void) launchParams:(NSDictionary *)params {

}
@end
```

Your app delegate only needs to know about the protocol, it doesn't care about your UIViewControllers.

When you get a push notification you check if the view controller conforms to the launch protocol.

```
...
    vcToOpen.modalPresentationStyle =UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

    if ([vcToOpen conformsToProtocol:@protocol(LaunchProtocol)]) {
        UIViewController <LaunchProtocol> *launchController = (UIViewController <LaunchProtocol> *) vcToOpen;

        NSDictionary* params = @{ /* create your param dict */ };
        [launchController launchParams:params];
    }

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:vcToOpen animated:YES completion:nil];
...
```

You would include the information from the push notification in the 'params' dict, and the UIViewController would extract what information it needs from it in launchParams:

```
- (void) launchParams:(NSDictionary *)params {
    NSLog(@"Username: %@", params[@"username"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use Singleton design pattern to achieve this. Create one shared instance class to store the values.

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

create properties inside the manager class which needs to be saved, then access the values from the  manager class.